# Cant build libgdx project

Tags: intellij-idea, netbeans, libgdx

I got the error that states "Unsupported class file major version 57" while trying to build LibGdx project, along with few other notifications. Same happens when trying to build using IntelliJ idea.

I have no idea how to fix that[image].

Comment: Just to understand, you have downloaded the gdx-setup.jar file at libgdx site and is trying to run it on your Netbeans or Intellij, correct? If so, I don't use NetBeans, however in Intellij  or Android Studio, after you create the project in the gdx-setup.jar  you should go to File - Open... select the file folder. When all the Gradle sync finishes, you go to Edit Configurator (right top menu).

Comment: Click on "+" and select "Application". Inside use name "Desktop", main class select "com.project.DesktopLauncher", on Working Directory, core/assets or android/assets folder and on Use classpath -> Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

"Unsupported class file major version 57" means your version of Java is incompatible with the one with which Gradle was compiled. You have to make sure that the Java version you are using is compatible to the Gradle version you are using. I guess you have either to downgrade your Java version or upgrade the Gradle version.